# What is the review process for automatic distribution of Extensions?

Tags: extension

Some extensions are eligible for being distributed automatically, which means that you can add them via the CiviCRM UI.

[This page](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Publish+an+Extension#PublishanExtension-EligibilityforAutomatedDistribution) lists the criteria that needs to be meet for automated distribution and we have an [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/openstreetmap-geocoding) ready for review.

Will I need to ask a CiviCRM site administrator to do the (manual) review? Or will they automatically be noticed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They'll automatically be noticed - I personally use http://civicrm.org/extensions/rss to keep track.  If we're being honest though, the extension review team isn't always the quickest to tackle something!  If you have something waiting in the queue, let me know and I'll make some time for it.

Comment: Thanks for the info ant the offer Jon. The extension that I linked to in my question is waiting to be reviewed so if you find the time, that would be great. The extension will provide free geocoding with open street map :)

Comment: Thanks Jon I learned something new from your answer - now I'm subscribed to the extension rss feed!

Comment: shall i do something to the View so the filter for 'is reviewed' is exposed or some such - it had never occured to me to check this before

Comment: @petednz-fuzion: I think an exposed filter would be great.

Comment: done on 'home' and on 'Adv Search'

Answer (score 0):

I'll be able to review it this weekend. On behalf of the community - thank you for a cool sounding extension!

Comment: Someone else got there first - never mind, used it and it was ace.